# Difference between input and output sections in a linkerfile?

Tags: linker, ld, elf, linker-scripts

While it could be clear in the context of a resulting binary or ELF file what is a section, many places in documentation (independently of the compiler used) refers them as to Input or Output sections.

What are the differences between these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker consumes object files (and possibly shared libraries) and outputs
an executable or shared library. The input object files are composed of named
sections - `.text`, `.data`, `.rodata`, `.bss`, etc. So is the output file.

It
is a principal part of the linker's job to combine all the *input* sections of
the same name, from all of the input object files, into a single *output* section
of that name in the output file. E.g. all of the `.text` sections of the input
object files contribute to the `.text` section of the output file.

Some input sections may discarded from the output file if the linker determines they are redundant.

Comment: In general terms, would the sections delimited in the source code(#pragma like) be input sections, and the sections referenced in the final linker-file be output sections?

Comment: @urnenfeld In Standard C or C++ there are no syntactic means to define sections. Section
definition normally is entirely the compiler's business. A compiler may have non-standard extensions that
let you assign an object to a named section. For GCC see the
documentation of `__attribute__ ((section ("<section-name>")))` in [Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) and [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)
Such extensions are for specialized purposes.

Comment: @urnenfeld Any sections that *are* defined with source-language extensions will become sections of the object files the compiler generates and will become *input* sections to the linker.