# How to implement custom output section in GNU LD?

Tags: c, eclipse, gnu, ld, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to define a custom output section in my application's LD file.  So far, this is what I've come up with...

```
MEMORY
{
  ...
  m_my_custom_section (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x00002400, LENGTH = 0x00000400
  ...
}

SECTIONS
{
  ...
  .my_custom_section :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.my_custom_section))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > m_my_custom_section
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, that's where I'm stuck.  I'm unsure how to specify which parts of my code I want assigned to that section when the application links.  Any help would be great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer [here in @Mike Kinghan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509585/difference-between-input-and-output-sections-in-a-linkerfile):

> In Standard C or C++ there are no syntactic means to define sections. Section definition normally is entirely the compiler's business. A compiler may have non-standard extensions that let you assign an object to a named section. For GCC see the documentation of `__attribute__ ((section ("<section-name>")))` in [Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) and [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) Such extensions are for specialized purposes.